# Reading COM DLL Tyep information in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using a COM DLL in VB.NET. I want to list out the classes in COM DLL implementing a specific Interface.
How can read the types which implements a specific Interface from .NET???

Comment: Use TryCast, it returns Nothing if the interface is not implemented.  Pretty unlikely you should be doing this, there is no mechanism in COM to discover coclasses at runtime.  Reflection is a .NET capability, not a COM feature.